# Storing the same words with one extra letter in a trie (example: bull and bully)

Tags: information-retrieval, trie

How can we store words like (bull and bully) and (bid and bide) in the same trie? If there is a leaf node at the 'y' in bully, is bull still stored on the same branch? Or will there be two branches from the first 'l' in bully, one leading to 'l' and the other leading to 'l' and 'y'?

Answer (score 1):

From root node of a trie, you can store all words by just passing characters as keys to the child nodes. We understand if there is a *end-of-word boolean* property is true, we know we have that word in our trie.

So for '*bull*' and '*bully*', we have *root > b > u > l > l* branch at the first place and for the last 'l' node we set end-of-word boolean property to true and we will add a child node to it which is 'y' node having end-of-word boolean property true as well. So, we will end up with *root > b > u > l > l > y*; the last l and y having end-of-word boolean properties are true, so we understand they are words.

Take a look at these pages for more clarity :

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/
- https://medium.com/basecs/trying-to-understand-tries-3ec6bede0014

Cheers